# Hook on MQGET and MQPUT

Tags: ibm-mq

When a message is dropped on a queue or removed from a queue, I would like to make an entry in a DB2 table. Is it possible to configure Websphere MQ with a hook on these operations?

Regards,

Yash

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, you can configure API exit programs for the queue manager, which are executed by the queue manager when processing the MQI API operations.

The MQ install includes only sample API exit programs.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.doc/q049280_.htm

Comment: Will the API exit program be able to perform the DB2 operation in the same transaction as the MQGET and MQPUT? I want to ensure that I write to the table only if the transaction that contains MQGET and MQPUT are successful.

Comment: I'd do the DB operations asynchronously, meaning that I'd use the API exit to put messages to a queue different than the target of the original put, and use a separate application to read this other queue and do the database operations based on the messages. The API exit can put messages to the second queue in the same MQ transaction as used for putting to the original target queue. This way the database operations will only start once the MQ transaction is committed.

Comment: I don't think that putting such logic in the messaging layer of your system is the best solution though, using an ESB would be much more flexible and easier to operate.

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose?  (of copying the messages to a DB)

Is it because you don't trust the sending and/or receiving application?  Or do you not trust MQ?  Or do you want a tool for finger-pointing? (blame-game)

Is it because the applications (sending or receiving) are NOT logging what they are doing?

If you are looking for a "message tracking solution" then there is a list of them at http://www.capitalware.com/mq_tools_comm.html#mqtrk

Comment: We have 2 sites. The DB hosted at one site is replicated to the other. If on Site1 a service sends a MQ message to another service, it will be persisted on MQ. If the whole site crashes due to a power failure, the MQ message will be lost. To get around this, I a think, I should get every message logged to the DB. This would get replicated to the other site. If Site 1 crashes, we will start the services on Site 2.  Before that, the messages that are logged to the table will be placed on the MQ, so that when the services start on Site 2, they can pick them for processing.

Comment: Does the Capitalware product ensure that the MQ message gets replicated only if the original transaction is successful? I know it uses api exits. An MQPUT may cause the exit func to be called. But if the transaction fails the replicated message should be removed.is this handled?

Comment: To answer your 1st comment, you should be using HA (High-Availability) do a search on 'MQ SRDF' but you may be able to use MQ Mutli-Instance.

Comment: To answer your 2nd comment, are you referring to MQ Message Replication (MQMR)?  If so, if your application is putting the message under a UOW (Unit of Work) then ALL messages will be under the UOW including those put by MQMR (either all will be committed or all will be rolled back). Hence, the answer is yes to your question.